# Primes that must occur in every composition series for a given module

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over the commutative noetherian ring $R$.  Let ${\cal C}(M)$ be the set of all primes $P$ in $R$ such that $R/P$ appears as a quotient in every composition series for $M$.  Clearly ${\cal C}(M)$ includes all the primes associated to $M$.  But it can contain other primes as well.  For example, let $R$ be the local ring of a singular point on an irreducible curve and let $M$ be the maximal ideal of $R$.  Then $R/M$ appears as a quotient in every composition series for $M$, but $M$ (as an ideal) is not associated to $M$ (as a module).

So:  Is there a nice characterization of the set ${\cal C}(M)$?

Comment: Hi Steven, nice question! I am just curious, could you share the motivation with us? 

Comment: Hailong:  Given two modules with the same support, one would ideally like to believe that they represent the same class in $K$-theory up to classes of modules from some well-behaved subcategory.  (This is true in the smooth case, with the well-behaved subcategory being modules of higher codimension --- but in the singular case one often wants a more restricted subcategory, e.g. modules that not only have higher codimension but also meet the singular locus in higher codimension.)  Primes in ${\cal C}(M)$ are potential obstructions to that program, so one wants to understand those primes.

Comment: Hailong:  The problem is interesting even in the smooth case; for understanding K-theory relative to a collection of subschemes, for example, where the "well behaved subcategory" should consist of modules that meet all those subschemes in higher codimensions.

Comment: I see, in fact I have a K-theoretic answer in mind! I will post it, but may be you can ask your original question, it looks very interesting!

Comment: Hi Steven, a silly question: if $P\cong Q$ as $R$-modules, do you consider them the same? I asked because for example if $R$ is a domain, then $(f) \cong (g)$ for any 2 elements $f,g$ but $R/(f)$ and $R/(g)$ are not isomorphic unless f=g*unit.

Comment: Hailong:  For the application I had in mind, I'd want to consider distinct prime ideals as different, even if they are the same as modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is a subtle question. The best result I am aware of is the following paper "Filtrations of Modules, the Chow Group, and the Grothendieck Group", by Jean Chan. She proved the following: Let $\mathcal F$ be any composition series of $M$. Let $c_i(\mathcal F)$ be the formal sum of primes of height $i$. Then  $c_0(\mathcal F), c_1(\mathcal F)$, as  elements in the  *Chow group*  of $R$, does not depend on the composition $\mathcal F$, so we can talk about $c_0(M), c_1(M)$.

So, for example, any such series will always contain the same minimal primes. As for height one primes, we only know that the sum of them is  constant up to *rational equivalences*. However, if there is only one height one prime (your example of local ring of curves), then you can deduce its presence in any series by showing $c_1(M) \neq 0$  in the Chow group of $R$.

I will also note that in Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra..." after  Proposition 3.7, the author remarks that modules which always have a filtration consisting only the associated primes are called *clean*. Clearly for clean modules one has $C(M) = Ass(M)$. There is no clean(!) criterion for cleanliness, as far as I know, but see this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0502282) for some partial results!